# How to tell the difference between the active and passive buzzer in Freenove arduino kit

Tags: arduino

I bought a Freenove ultimate starter kit, and it comes with two buzzers. It says that one is active and the other one is passive, and the active buzzer had a sticky label on it. The only differences are that on one the pins are slightly higher and lower, and one has a green bottom and the other one does not, where you can see the curcuit board through. im new to stack overflow, so any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The question is which buzzer is active, and which buzzer is passive

Comment: active buzzes connected to 5 V or HIGH pin. passive buzzes only with tone() function or with some other way to generate a frequency on the pin

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial documentation, the active buzzer has a "waterproof coating" on the pin side, so the one with the exposed solder points is the passive buzzer.